# rxjs: what is the best way to dynamically add values to an observable stream?

Tags: rxjs, stream

As part of learning rxjs ive been using create methods of, from, interval etc. to test throttle and deboucne etc ive been creating streams using fromevent.

now i have a real use case and i need to dynamically add values into an empty observable stream. i cant find any examples on how best to do this NOT using the creation methods above. Presently Im using a BehaviourSubject to dynamically add items to a stream using next(). Is this the best/preferred way of DYNAMICALLY adding new items to a stream?

e.g.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, mapTo, concatMap, } from 'rxjs/operators';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const example = subject.pipe(
  concatMap(ev => timer(200).pipe(mapTo(ev))),
  tap((ev) => console.log(ev))
)
example.subscribe();

// add a flurry of values dynamically
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
subject.next(4);

// some time later add some more
setTimeout(function(){ 
  subject.next(5);
  subject.next(6);
  subject.next(7);
}, 5000);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-simpleexample-gyrtw8?file=index.ts

Thanks

Comment: This is definitely a way to accomplish what you want but it would be interesting to know what in reality your `function` is, I mean the `function` embedded in the `setTimeout`. If `setTimeout` simulates some sort of `callback` based mechanism there may be alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a veeery custom logic of adding values that should be emitted in an Observable, you can create your own (instead of using `fromEvent, of, from, ...`):

```
const myObservable = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.next(2);
  subscriber.next(3);

  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(4);
    subscriber.next(5);


    setTimeout(() => {
       subscriber.next(6);
    }, 2000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

However, the rxjs's creation functions should cover 99% of your needs.
The code above can be also written like:

```
concat(
  of(1,2,3),
  of(4,5).pipe(
    delay(1000)
  ),
  of(6).pipe(
    delay(2000)
  )
)
```

---

UPD: About Subjects

Subject is also an Observable so in your case using Subject is applicable but might not be the best option. The idea of a Subject is that there can be more than one subscriber (the one who uses the values from subject) but I'm not sure that it's your case (by the way - you can provide your real-life example to help us understand what you want to achieve)